# Making a scrolling menu using positon: fixed;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website (http://www.deayoga.ch/), and I'd like to make the menu bar on the left scroll with the page. In other words, it would start on the page as it is, and then, when the user scrolls down, it would stay fixed, relative to the browser window. The idea comes from the links on the right hand side on some StackOverflow pages, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).
How could I achieve this?


PS: I already know how to make a div stay fixed on the left, using `position: fixed; left: 0;`, but my question is how to do this in the middle of the page, without knowing the distance from the side of the window (since the page sits in the middle, regardless of window size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remy Sharp has a very nice tutorial (with video) on how to do exactly this:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I'm sure this will work. Still, just as a point of interest, how would I detect when the user scrolls (and by how much) without third-party scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a math problem... use JS to get the window size, divide by two to get the mid-point, subtract half the size of your fixed div from the mid-point value, then set your CSS position "left" value to that.

Comment: I was thinking he meant middle as in horizontally center. You can use the same technique for the vertical as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Actually, it just didn't occur to me to use js to calculate the left position, I was more focused on the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this tto your stylesheet instead of the class you have now for `#leftcol`

```
#leftcol {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then add the following to your `#container` class:

```
position: relative;
```

Your menu is now in the middle of the page. You might need to reposition the content though... just add a margin.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, though I think you might of misunderstoood my question: it wasn't about how to fix the element is the center vertically, but how to make it start normally and only when the user scrolls down (and the div _touches_ _the_ _top_ _of_ _the_ _screen_) make it fixed. Thanks anyway!